# slim php function menu grom database

Tags: php, slim, idiorm

I a trying to generate a menu for a webshop. I have written a method for it.

Slim says "undefined variable on line 53. I have marked the line with ***

Class Menu {

```
function generate_menu() {
    $menu = 'ul';
    $catergory = Model::factory('category')->find_many();

    ***foreach ($category as $item) {***
        $menu .= '<li>';
        $menu .= '<a href = "' . $item->link . '">' . $item->title . '</a>';
        $menu .= '</li>';

        $count = Model::factory('sub_category')->where('category_title', $item->title)->count();
        if ($count >= 0) {
            $sub_catergory = Model::factory('sub_category')->where('category_title', $item->title)->find_many();
            $menu .= '<ul>';
            foreach ($sub_catergory as $sub_catergory) {
                $menu .= '<li>';
                $menu .= '<a href = "' . $sub_category->link . '">' . $sub_category->title . '</a>';
                $menu .= '</li>';
            }
            $menu .= '</ul>';
        }
    }
    $menu .= '</ul>';
    return $menu;
}
```

}

Could someone show me how to pass this function to the template in slim php ?

This is the get request i am trying to pass the returned $menu variable to.

```
$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
        $site_info = Model::factory('Site_info')->where('id', '1')->find_one();

        $app->render('front_page.php', array(
            'site_name' => $site_info->site_name,
            'site_slogan' => $site_info->site_slogan,
            'domain' => $site_info->domain
        ));
    });
```

Also could someone point me in the right direction to what paris returns if a database request returns nothing?

Comment: You really shouldn't perform DB queries within a loop.

Comment: I have already solved it! I made some really dumb typos and the menu is generated as it should be now.

Comment: Ok thiefmaster. I am just starting to learn Php. What would be a better option?

Comment: Fetch all the menu items in a single query. Oh, and since you already solved your problem: Please delete the question (if it's unlikely to be useful for other users) or post the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My method for creating the menu :

```
Class Menu {

function generate_menu() {
    $menu = '<ul>';
    $category = Model::factory('category')->find_many();

    foreach ($category as $item) {
        $menu .= '<li>';
        $menu .= '<a href = "' . $item->link . '">' . $item->title . '</a>';
        $menu .= '</li>';

        $count = Model::factory('sub_category')->where('category_title', $item->title)->count();
        if ($count >= 0) {
            $sub_category = Model::factory('sub_category')->where('category_title', $item->title)->find_many();
            $menu .= '<ul>';
            foreach ($sub_category as $value) {
                $menu .= '<li>';
                $menu .= '<a href = "' . $value->link . '">' . $value->title . '</a>';
                $menu .= '</li>';
            }
            $menu .= '</ul>';
        }
    }
    $menu .= '</ul>';
    return $menu;
}
```

}

After that i assigned the method output to a variable and passed it to the template :

```
$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
        $site_info = Model::factory('Site_info')->where('id', '1')->find_one();

        $category_menu = Menu::generate_menu();
        $app->render('front_page.php', array(
            'site_name' => $site_info->site_name,
            'site_slogan' => $site_info->site_slogan,
            'domain' => $site_info->domain,
            'menu' => $category_menu
        ));
    });
```